# mod_rewrite is being too strict

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a rewrite rule that is too strict.

```
RewriteRule ^folder/([^/\.]+)/?$ file.php?$1 [L]
```

This redirects http://www.domain.com/folder/$variable to http://www.domain.com/file.php?$variable HOWEVER.. if the variable has any dots or slashes it fails. I want it to redirect to  http://www.domain.com/file.php? even if $variable is empty or contains any characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `([^/\.]+)` to `(.*?)`.

The first matches at least one of anything except dots and forward slashes. The second matches 0 or more of anything, up to the posibility of a trailing slash (because of the `/?$` at the end of your regex).